# Mysql write query to filter (column1- sum(something)) > 0

Tags: mysql

i have query:

```
SELECT cf_1095,@sum:=sum(amount), accountingpaidamount,     
DATE_FORMAT(paymentdate ,'%d/%m/%Y') as tanggal,
DATE_FORMAT(due_date ,'%d/%m/%Y') as tgljatuhtempo, 
vtiger_servicecontracts.subject as kodetb,
vtiger_contactdetails.contactid as memberid,
campaignname as nokk,
vtiger_contactdetails.firstname as namadepan,
vtiger_contactdetails.lastname as  namabelakang,
vtiger_leaddetails.lastname as tipekartu,
cf_1085 as namabank,
cf_1095-sum(amount) as kuranggesek
FROM `vtiger_accounting_payments`, vtiger_accounting,
vtiger_servicecontracts,vtiger_servicecontractscf,     
vtiger_crmentity,vtiger_user2role, vtiger_role, 
vtiger_users,vtiger_leaddetails, vtiger_contactdetails, vtiger_campaign
WHERE
vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vtiger_accounting_payments.idtransaction
and vtiger_accounting.accountingrelated2=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid
and vtiger_servicecontractscf.servicecontractsid=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid
and accountingtype='Pelunasan Gesek'
and vtiger_accounting_payments.idtransaction=vtiger_accounting.accountingid
and vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0
and vtiger_user2role.userid=vtiger_users.id
and vtiger_crmentity.smcreatorid=vtiger_user2role.userid
and vtiger_user2role.roleid=vtiger_role.roleid
and vtiger_users.user_name='stafroyal'
and cf_1091=leadid
and vtiger_contactdetails.contactid=vtiger_servicecontracts.contactid 
and
vtiger_campaign.campaignid=cf_1155
and date_format(paymentdate,'%Y-%m-%d') < date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-%d') 
group by idtransaction
order by vtiger_servicecontracts.subject
```

query above successfully display results correctly and column "kuranggesek" will display amount of numbers.

what i am trying to accomplish is  I want to add  filter

```
and  (cf_1095-sum(amount))>0
```

so zero result on column kuranggesek will be eliminated. But if add those filter, i get error:

```
Invalid use of group function
```

can you help me how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: use `having (cf_1095-sum(amount))>0` instead for and filter

Comment: @Devisy how much time it take to execute ?

Comment: hi vipin it takes about 5secs

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using aggregate functions in where clause use having clause.

The `WHERE` clause filters which rows MySQL selects. Then MySQL groups the rows together and aggregates the numbers for your COUNT function.

`HAVING` is like WHERE, only it happens after the COUNT value has been computed, so it'll work as you expect.

```
....
group by idtransaction
having kuranggesek>0
order by vtiger_servicecontracts.subject
```

Comment: @jeevabalan1995 Depend from application. But, I think that this query from some report, and you're right. This no  
frequently query

Comment: hi jeeva i have this works in my query. thank u so much!